# Match text between empty lines

Tags: java, regex, text

I have a text in following blocks:

```
AAAAAAA
BBBBBBB
CCCCCCC

DDDDDD.    YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY                
EEEEE 1234567890                              

Some random text
Some text random
Random text
Text 
Some random text

ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
```

How to select with regexp a following **block**?

```
Some random text
Some text random
Random text
Text 
Some random text
```

From the original text I know that this **block** goes after line  `DDDDDD.    YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY` which is optionally followed by line `EEEEE 1234567890` and also that **block** is between lines that contain only \s symbols.

I have tried pattern `DDDDDD.*\\s+(.*)\\s+` it doesn't work.

Comment: As with so many regex questions, the easiest way is probably not to use a regular expression; instead just look for those strings and newlines using `indexOf`.

Comment: not very clear. why the previous block is not captured?

Comment: I think it  is an overkill for regex. [`DDDDDD\.[ ]+YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY[ ]+\r?\n(\s*\S++.*+)?(?:\r?\n){2}((?:\s*\S+.*+)+)(?:\r?\n){2}`](https://regex101.com/r/zL7zF1/2). Really, try something else. You know the requirements better. Try splitting by double newline sequence, check the preceding elements.

Comment: So far `^DDDDDD.*$^(.*)$` works with MULTILINE and DOTALL and captures block `Some random text
Some text random
Random text
Text 
Some random text

ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU`

Comment: http://regexr.com/3cb9g - This works in js : `DDDDDD\..*\n(?:EEEEE 1234567890.*\n)?\s*\n((?:.*\n)*)(?!.)`

Comment: Thanks guys for suggestions :) I appreciate your help. I am voting on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `Pattern` to match your expected text:

```
String text = "AAAAAAA\nBBBBBBB\nCCCCCCC\n\nDDDDDD.    YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY                "
    + "\nEEEEE 1234567890                              "
    + "\n\nSome random text\nSome text random\nRandom text\nText \nSome random text\n\n"
    + "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ\nUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
 // | 6 "D"s
 // |    | actual dot
 // |    |  | some whitespace
 // |    |  |   | 22 "Y"s
 // |    |  |   |    | more whitespace
 // |    |  |   |    |   | optional: 
 // |    |  |   |    |   || 5 "E"s
 // |    |  |   |    |   ||   | whitespace
 // |    |  |   |    |   ||   |  | 10 digits
 // |    |  |   |    |   ||   |  |      | more whitespace including line breaks
 // |    |  |   |    |   ||   |  |      |      | your text
 // |    |  |   |    |   ||   |  |      |      |    | followed by any "Z" sequence
    "D{6}\\.\\s+Y{22}\\s+(E{5}\\s\\d{10}\\s+)?(.+?)(?=Z+)", 
    Pattern.DOTALL
);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

**Output**

```
Some random text
Some text random
Random text
Text 
Some random text
```

**Note**

Not sure how to delimit the final part, so I just used a capitalized `Z` sequence (1+).

Up to you to refine.

Comment: Ty Mena for the working solution and comments in it. :)